# Show that the ratio between two numbers is always proportional to the the maximum percentage error of their average?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio, error-propagation

The question is this: if we have a set of any random consecutive numbers, for example {1, 1.2, 4.2, 4.8, 5.6, 7.4, 9.8} then how can we prove that calculating the ratio between each of the numbers and picking the largest ratio will give the largest percentage error between the average of the two numbers and the numbers themselves.

Additionally we define the domain of the set to be $$x > 0$$

In this example, you would take the ratio 1.2/1 = 1.2, 4.2/1.2 = 3.5, 4.8/4.2= 1.143..., 5.6/4.8=1.161..., 7.4/5.6= 1.321..., 9.8/7.4=1.324... .

We can see that the largest ratio is 3.5, so we assume that the average of 4.2 and 1.2 = 2.7, will have the largest percentage error w.r.t. either 4.2 or 1.2.

The percentage error would be equal to the difference between the average and either of the two numbers (which in any case will be equal to half the difference between the two numbers) divided by the average itself:

Average: $$((4.2+1.2)/2)$$
Percentage error: $$\frac{((4.2-1.2)/2)}{((4.2+1.2)/2)}$$

Now, instead substituting numerical values for letters,the problem boils down to the following:

Prove that the greatest or least value of $$x/y$$ will always give you the greatest or least value of $$\frac{((x-y)/2)}{((x+y)/2)}$$ which is also equal to $$\frac{(x-y)}{(x+y)}$$

Comment: Can we assume the random numbers are positive, or something along those lines?  What happens if you can select both $x$ and $-x$?

Comment: This is false as stated.  Suppose your random numbers are $\{-1.01,1,2\}$.  Then the maximal ratio is $2=\frac 21$ but your error function is maximized by taking $F(-1.01,1)=\frac {-1.01-1}{-1.01+1}=\frac {2.01}{.01}=201$.

Comment: Of course, lulu, it seems you are correct. The formulae are not valid for negative numbers or cases where x and -x are taken as the numbers needed. I will restrict the domain of the set to account for this. Thank you.

Comment: If you assume the random numbers are all positive, then the statement is true.  I will post a solution below.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Assume $0 < y < x$. You state that the ratio $\frac{x}{y}$ is **proportional** to something you call a percentage error, given by $\frac{x - y}{x + y}$. In other words, you claim that there is a **proportionality constant** $c > 0$ such that $\frac{x}{y} = c \cdot \frac{x - y}{x + y}$. This is equivalent to $c = \frac{x(x+y)}{y(x-y)}$. However, $\frac{3(3+2)}{2(3-2)} = \frac{15}{2} \neq \frac{6}{1} = \frac{2(2+1)}{1(2-1)}$ shows that $c$ is **not constant**. So we have a contradiction, and your statement must be false.

Comment: Hi, sorry - I used the word "proportional" very loosely, and what I really meant to say was that if given all ratios of $y/x$ in ascending order you could assume that the percentage error of the average w.r.t. either y or x would be in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the values are positive.

Consider the function $$F(z)=\frac {z-1}{z+1}$$

It is easy to differentiate:  $$F'(z)=\frac 2{(z+1)^2}$$  The derivative is strictly positive so the function is strictly increasing (at least for $z>-1$).  Thus it reaches its maximum when $z$ is maximal, and its minimum when $z$ is minimal.  But taking $z=\frac xy$ we see that this is your "maximal error" function.

Comment: How do you prove the same is true however, for values of $y \neq 1$?

Comment: In my expression, $z=\frac xy$.  I have rewritten your error function in terms of the ratio (by multiplying numerator and denominator by $\frac 1y$. That is to say, your error function evaluated at the point $(x,y)$ equals mine evaluated at $\frac xy$.  As to the max/min, I believe I meant it as I wrote it.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you! Also, I'm interested to know how you solved this so quickly? What was your thought process, especially on the key point of setting z=x/y?

Comment: No problem.  Your test function is homogeneous....i.e.  $F(x,y)=F(\lambda x, \lambda y)$ for non-zero $\lambda$.  That means it is a function of the ratio. Once you know that then you just have to look at how it grows as a function of the ratio.